# GWT site works fine but will not render in SuperDevMode

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I have spent the day trying to get my GWT 2.6 project to use SuperDevMode. I got to the point where I can get SuperDevMode, codeserver etc fired up in Chrome (Also tested in Firefox, linux and windows) however no amount of research seems adequate to progress me beyond the point I'm stuck on:

The site works fine when run as a normal server, (And it used to work fine in Classic Devmode) I'm reasonably convinced there's nothing fundamentally wrong with it, but as soon as I switch to SuperDevMode the GWT module won't load. I get the static content only.

First off I found an error in the Console of Chrome Developer Tools. I get a stack trace that claims that the method getCalendarFactory of my ClientFactory can't be called on an undefined reference (But again, without SuperDevMode this doesn't happen)

```
Uncaught com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Exception caught: Exception caught: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'getCalendarFactory' of undefined
SimpleEventBus.java:203
$doFire_0 SimpleEventBus.java:203
$fireEvent_1 SimpleEventBus.java:88
fireEvent_7 SimpleEventBus.java:52
$goTo PlaceController.java:156
$handleHistoryToken PlaceHistoryHandler.java:192
$handleCurrentHistory PlaceHistoryHandler.java:118
$onModuleLoad XXXAppController.java:62init_1 com_00046XXX_00046XXX_00046XXX__EntryMethodHolder.java:3
apply_0 Impl.java:283
entry0 Impl.java:347
(anonymous function) Impl.java:92gwtOnLoad XXX-0.js:46819
(anonymous function) Comparators.java:32
```

I've looked very hard through this but I'm still at a loss to understand the stack trace. After a few hours I decided to comment out a line from my AppController class (Which is serving as the entry-point in the gwt.xml):

```
// historyHandler.handleCurrentHistory();
```

However now when I load the page in SuperDevMode, I don't get the exception anymore, I get nothing except static content, no errors or output from the GWT module, so the UmbrellaException is gone but nothing else has changed really.

Any help or direction would be very gratefully received.

Comment: No need to write "Thanks, [My Name]" - please keep short and concise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use maven? If that's the case, have you lunch your superDevMode server on a container as Tomcat/Jetty ?

To see if your superDevMode's server works, you need to go to the url "127.0.0.1/9876". If you have no server which responds that's your superDevMode is not lunch.

More information on :
http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the codeserver on port 9876 is fine. I can step and set breakpoints etc.

Comment: I had same error when i used deserialization, in general this error occur when variable wasn't initialize. But i can't see why this error occur in SuperDevMode. What have you had in your SuperDevMode Module ? You have no error when you compile with SuperDevMode ?